# Formula to return multiple values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet below attempting to capture which addresses have magazine subscriptions.  It's broken out as follows:

1. Tab 1 lists the name of the magazines (column D).  More on column H later.
2. Tab 2 is the delivery report.  Column A lists the addresses which received each magazine (column D).

I'd like to devise a formula showing all the addresses thatreceived each magazine in column H of tab 1.  Unfortunately, I'm unable to figure out a way to do this, as I would need this formula to output multiple values/addresses.  Column H is formatted to how I would want this to look.

Is it possible for anyone to advise?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you want for output?  You are only showing a single row and a single worksheet.  Yet you refer to two `tabs` and multiple customers/fruits.

Comment: Do you mean that columns A & B are from the `January` worksheet.  And you have other worksheets that are not shown?  What are we looking at in columns `I:O`?  Why is only a single line populated?  Why are there duplicate customers in column `I` if you want some kind of summary? I think you need to edit your question to show better what you want for results, and what your data is really like.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I've re-framed the question and example to something that is more accurate to the situation I'm working on.

Comment: @steiger What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld whichever is the most recent included in Office365

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thank you for providing this formula. Unfortunately we are only getting the first result, similar to a VLookup. Is there any additional to add to the formula, or something we are missing?

Comment: @steiger There's probably something you are missing, but I cannot tell what from the information you provide.

Comment: @steiger As you can see from my screenshot, the formula returns all of the matches.  Suggest you examine the differences between what I provided and what you really have, and how you adapted the formula.  You can try entering the formula with `ctrl+shift+enter`, but since you have a modern version of Excel, I would be surprised if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Index/Aggregate:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$2:$A$10)/($A$2:$A$10=$D2),COLUMN(A1))),"")
```

[image]

---

If one has the Dynamic Array Formula FILTER:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=D2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- On Tab2, I created a `Table` for the data.
- I named the table `Tab2Tbl` and the relevant column headers are `Magazines`.
- `Addresses` are in column 1 of that table.

**Tab2Tbl**

[image]

The formula for the Addresses in Column H of Tab 1:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,INDEX(FILTER(Tab2Tbl,Tab2Tbl[Magazines]=D2),0,1))
```

**Tab 1**

[image]

*If you do not have the `FILTER` function, then you can use:*

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,INDEX(Tab2Tbl[Addresses],N(IF(1,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(Tab2Tbl[Magazines]=D2)*ROW(Tab2Tbl)-ROW(Tab2Tbl[#Headers]),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNTIF(Tab2Tbl[Magazines],D2))))))))
```